# Why does my terminal window say android before the user?

Tags: bash, prompt

This is what is looks like when I open a new terminal. Im not sure what the text before the ~ user$ is supposed to mean but it seems really weird that is says android-some_alphanumeric_id. 

[image]

Comment: Is your terminal running on an Android phone? I guess this is the hostname.

Comment: No Im running it on my mac.

Comment: That's probably your host name for some reason. What does `hostname` print out? Or it could be your user name; check with `id`. Finally, if it's not one of them, the output of `declare -p PS1` please.

Comment: The text before the username means the machine's current hostname. It should match the output of the `hostname` command, or the contents of `/etc/hostname`.

Comment: Sounds like your network administrator either mixed up some address pools on the DHCP server, or has a sly sense of humor.

Comment: *probably*, but canonically it's coming from $PS1, which is what's pulling in the host name

Comment: I got a very similar host name yesterday while connected over Wi-Fi to a university campus network. Once disconnected, my Mac got his "normal" host name back. (Verified before and after disconnecting by running `hostname` on the command line). It might be some commercial DHCP server that uses that as the default naming convention for hosts joining the network.

Comment: And it's not impossible that `PS1` has  a local, customized value, though the `hostname` explanation certainly seems the most plausible.

Answer (score 6):

By default, the prompt you see when opening a terminal is defined by the variable $PS1, which usually contains:

```
$ echo $PS1
\h:\W \u\$
```

Where \h is the host name.

A DHCP server can assign a host name to a machine connecting to its network (e.g. "managed" by that server): https://askubuntu.com/a/239446/77137

So basically when you connected to that network, your host name was (temporarily) changed to android-that_alphanumeric_id. Although your local configuration is stored in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist (not to be edited manually) and shouldn't be affected. On a Mac you can check with:

```
grep -A1 LocalHostName /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

I got a very similar host name yesterday while connected over Wi-Fi to a university campus network. Once disconnected, my Mac got his normal/local host name back – verified before and after disconnecting by running `hostname` on the command line.
It might be some commercial DHCP server (popular with in academic environments, apparently) that uses that as the default naming convention for hosts joining the network.